# No Connected Devices Found in android studio when run app that i want in my emulator android api 30

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, emulation

and raise this error:
No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions.

i expecting run my app in android studio
how can resolve it
i checkout my emulator on device manager and see the android api was listed in emulator that i want to use it is not listed in downloaded list in emulators and i download it manually
but my problem not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making sure that you downloaded the desired android Version, user version 34 as its the newest, link it to the simulator you want.

Next go into devices and manually turn on the device, wait for it to load then press the run button